# How do I change the destination IP of all outgoing packets (especially DNS)?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, traffic, stack

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with the latest build of (Debian) raspberry pi OS. I am trying to configure `iptables` to redirect all traffic coming from the Pi (with ) to another machine (lets say with an IP address ). This is to test the other machine which will host a DNS based captive portal and I want to forward all traffic to that captive portal machine (IP B). If I could keep the SSH connection unforwarded that would be great because I like my headless setup.

I have already tried this set of rules on the NAT table (`iptables`). I realise what I already tried only tries to forward UDP traffic from IP A to IP B. This didn't work.

```
root@pi4:/home/pi# iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 1155 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       <IP A>               <resolver IP>       udp dpt:53 to:<IP B>

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 1155 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Any help or pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't touched `iptables` in a while, but I'm pretty sure all you need to do is make the other machine your DNS gateway and give the Pi its own subnet. Then all the `iptables` commands to do what you need to do would be on that other machine.

Comment: I understand your suggestion. The only thing is that I'd prefer to have the source IP of every packet to get changed from <resolver IP> to <IP B> so that this emulates a real life scenario where the Pi tries to connect to a DNS based captive portal. Unless there is another way to emulate this without IP tables...

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! Turns out that my chain rules were just placed in the wrong place. I should have placed my PREROUTING rule into OUTPUT since I wanted to modify and internally generated destination IP address. In the end, my NAT table looked like this (keeping the placeholder IPs from the question):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [22:2797]
:INPUT ACCEPT [22:2797]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [129:8883]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [129:8883]
-A OUTPUT -d <resolver IP>/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination <IP B>:<port B>
-A POSTROUTING -d <IP B>/32 -p udp -m udp --dport <port B> -j SNAT --to-source <IP A>
COMMIT
# Completed on
```